# Максимальное число в js

Tags: javascript

В чем заключается разница между Number.MAX_VALUE и Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER кроме числового значения?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799226/whats-the-difference-between-js-number-max-safe-integer-and-max-value

Comment: @entithat немного не понял как мне это должно помочь. В каких ситуациях использовать Number.MAX_VALUE, а в каких Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Comment: Когда Вам нужно максимально возможное число (но не `Infinity`), используйте `Number.MAX_VALUE`. Когда нужно максимально возможное целое без потери точности - используйте `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: @ИванСорокин, а приведи пример для чего, ты бы хотел использовать эти значения?

Comment: @Yaant я немного не понимаю значение слов "без потери точности"

Comment: @ИванСорокин, это значит можешь получить любое число меньше. А вот с больше - будут проблемы, пример которых есть в ответах по ссылке в первом комментарии, например `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, понял

Answer (score 5):

Константа [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) представляет максимальное безопасное целочисленное значение в JavaScript (2<sup>53</sup>-1). Константа [`MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) имеет значение `9007199254740991`.

Смысл этого числа в том, что в JavaScript используется формат чисел с плавающей запятой двойной точности, как определено в стандарте IEEE 754, а он может безопасно представлять числа только в диапазоне от -(2<sup>53</sup>-1) до 2<sup>53</sup>-1.

Свойство [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) представляет максимальное числовое значение, представимое в JavaScript. Свойство `MAX_VALUE` имеет значение, приблизительно равное `1.79E+308`. Значения, большие MAX_VALUE представляются как «бесконечность».

Comment: это перевод какого-то из ответов по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799226/whats-the-difference-between-js-number-max-safe-integer-and-max-value ?

Comment: похоже вот [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57799543/2881286) - стоит добавить это в ответ

Comment: нет, это из документации вырезки.

Comment: Тогда ссылку на документацию добавь :)

Comment: Всегда с удовольствием)